# Translate Bitbucket Pipeline to circleCI

Tags: reactjs, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm in some troubles to get my CircleCI implementation working.

Since now, I've been using BitbucketPipelins but we would like to move to CircleCI.
I would like to "translate" my bitbucketpipeline file to a circleCI. I'm getting this error : Directory (/) you are trying to checkout to is not empty and not a git repository.

My bitbucket pipeline :

```
image:
  name: kuara/node-caprover:2.0
  username: $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
  password: $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
  email: $DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL
  
definitions:
  caches:
    node : node-modules

pipelines:
  branches:
    main:
      - step:
          name: Build React App
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
            - CI=false npm run build
            - tar -cvf deploy.tar --exclude='*.map' --exclude="node-modules/*" captain-definition build/*
          artifacts:
            - deploy.tar
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Caprover
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - caprover deploy --caproverUrl $CAPROVER_URL --caproverPassword $CAPROVER_PASSWORD --caproverApp $CAPROVER_APP -t deploy.tar
```

And this is what I've done with CircleCI :

```
version: 2.1

orbs :
  node : circleci/node@5.0.0

executors : 
  my-executor : 
    docker : 
      - image : kuara/node-caprover:2.0
        auth :
          username : kuara
          password : $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
    
jobs :
  build_react_app : 
    working_directory: /
    executor : my-executor
    steps : 
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys :
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run :
          name : Installing dependencies
          command : npm install --production
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run :
          name : Building
          command : CI=false npm run build
      - run : 
          name : Creating .tar file
          command : tar -cvf deploy.tar --exclude='*.map' --exclude="node-modules/*" captain-definition build/*
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: /
          paths:
            - deploy.tar

  deploy_to_kuara : 
    working_directory: /
    executor : my-executor
    steps : 
      - checkout
      - attach_workspace:
          at: /
      - run: |
          if [ -f "/deploy.tar" ]; then
            echo "It worked!";
          else
            echo "Nope!"; exit 1
          fi

workflows:
  build_deploy :
    jobs : 
      - build_react_app:
          context: Kuara Caprover
      - deploy_to_kuara:
          context: Kuara Caprover
          requires: 
            - build_react_app
```

Comment: I believe you can't `checkout` "into" the `/` directory; exactly for the reasons stated in the error message. Why do you want/need to do all that in `/`?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the working directory for your entire job to `/`. Because of this it is attempting to clone the repo into the `/` path, which (as the error indicates) is not empty. It's probably best if you do not override the default working directory if you do not have a specific need to do that. If you do need to override the working directory for the whole job you should do this to a path that is guaranteed to be empty every time (i.e. `/tmp/mydir`).